# GCC Preprocessing: Leave undefined Conditionals without assuming zero-values

Tags: c, parsing, gcc, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm using GCC to preprocess some C-files.

Examplesource:

```
#define A 1
#define B 0

#if A && B > 0
  bla()
#else
  #if C == 0
    foo()
  #else
    foo2()
  #endif
  foo3()
#endif
```

I'm running this from a batchfile which leaves Comments (`-CC`) and does not work through macros (`-fdirectives-only`):

```
gcc -E -CC -fdirectives-only -Wundef infile.c > outfile.c
```

It gives me the following output for the above example because it assumes C=0 automatically:

```
foo()
foo3()
```

I'd want the following output (NO assumptions taken by GCC):

```
  #if C == 0
    foo()
  #else
    foo2()
  #endif
  foo3()
```

Is there ANY way to do that? I know that's just how the GCC *SHOULD* work, but maybe by doing some manual work, it could be done - do you have any idea?

I know, the alternative Coan would make this possible - but I'm not allowed to use it :-(

Thanks in advance!

---

**SORRY GUYS, I MEANT TO #define A & B. EDITED MY SOURCE**

Comment: Preprocessing lines are processed before any of the other source is compiled. The `A` and `B` in `#if A && B > 0` have nothing to do with any `A = 1` or `B = 0` source lines.  Names which aren't `#define`d already are replaced with `0` for purposes of preprocessor arithmetic.

Comment: Your input and your output don't match. I suspect some copy/paste error.

Comment: Just what is `A = 1` and `B = 0`? It is not valid C.

Comment: That behavior is defined by the standard. You could use `#ifdef C` to test for definedness, or use `#if defined(C) && C==0` for things, but you can't tell the preprocessor not to execute preprocessing directives.

Comment: Do you have a real use case for this feature? I guess that this feature is not available in the GCC preprocessor.

Comment: `#if !defined(A) || !defined(B) || !defined(C)  #error No wonder it isn't working. #endif`.

Comment: Sorry gues I meant `#define A 1 #define B 0`...

Comment: @skyking: Yes I have... I have source code which is automatically generated from graphical coding which has thousands of #if/#else-blocks within a sourcefile. Now I want to display the *real* source for a certain configuration of #defines. But everything which is not defined should NOT be stripped away as the user should see, that he has to #define those variables.

Comment: So Coan solves your problem, but you are not allowed to use it? This sounds like a completely artificial problem.  You are asking how to simplify preprocessor directives ("ANY way to do that") and don't want one of the ANY ways.  What's the issue here?

Comment: @Ira Baxter: ANY way of doing it manually without implementing a whole new parser. I don't understand why you question my wish/goal - it's totally valid. And furthermore I don't understand people downvoting questions which are well described and totally valid. But this page is becoming more and more some sort of a troll-page, especially since it gained so much attention / so many new users, as you can find nearly all questions on the first google page when looking for *anything*

Comment: If you want to on partially run the preprocessor, GCC won't do that that.  Now you something that will do that.  Your choices: use something that exists, or (great effort) make one of your own. Using Coan isn't implementing a whole new parser.  Apparently it exists and all you have to do is fetch it.   Yes, I get to question your wish; you're asking for my attention, and so far your wish/goal doesn't make any sense.  (I didn't downvote anything here).

Comment: My wish actually DOES make sense a lot, but I won't discuss this further. You probably didn't work in a business environment with certain restrictions. I asked here because I didn't know whether I missed something easy or whether there is some way of enabling GCC to work that way. That is what this page is about: Ask something you don't know. **And only because the answer is "No, there isn't", does NOT mean the question is senseless**.

Comment: So you aren't *allowed* to download open source software?  You didn't tell us that earlier.  (You: "Boss, I need X to do my job".  Boss: "You can't have it".  Tough place to work).   The only thing you've told us is you have GCC.  It won't do what you want.  You didn't tell us what else you have, so there's hardly a way to address "other easy methods".   No, you can't do this without writing a parser/preprocessor/algebraic simplifier.   I gave you the best answer you could get with the minimal information you supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this without some third-party application. Neither GCC nor clang include this functionality, which is why third-party tools exist.